# Query Optimization on MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

I’m new entry on this tune db, i want to ask for how to optimize the query when the data reach around 35 millions. I’ve been read on several forum to do this below task, but it's not improving my query as per expected.

1. Creating the index on all fields that I need to specified.
2. I sequence the where clause from the maximum cardinality.
3. using the where clause on the specified data.
4. have done the optimize table command, analyze table command

I hope someone can gave me clue on this :)

My query

```
SELECT  a.msisdn, a.service, a.adn, a.operator, a.channel_subscribe,
        a.subscribed_from, b.blacklist_status, b.date_created,
        b.status, b.price
    FROM  `xmp_new`.`subscription` a
    INNER JOIN  msisdntools.`subscription_import` b ON a.msisdn = b.msisdn
    WHERE  b.msisdn IN (
        SELECT  msisdn
            FROM  `xmp_new`.`subscription`
            WHERE  msisdn NOT IN (
                SELECT  msisdn
                    FROM  `msisdntools`.`tbl_blacklist`
                    WHERE  blacklist_status='1'
                      AND  active='1'
                          )
              AND  msisdn NOT IN (
                SELECT  msisdn
                    FROM  subscription_import
                    WHERE  DATE(date_created)=DATE(NOW())
                          )
              AND  operator = 'xxxx'
              AND  subscribed_from BETWEEN DATE('2015-05-16') AND DATE('2015-05-17')
                       )
      AND  DATE(b.date_created) = '2012-05-16'
      AND  b.STATUS = 0
      AND  b.price IS NULL;
```

The index of subscription_import

```
    Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
    subscription_import     0   PRIMARY     1   id  A   33136464    (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE        
    subscription_import     1   msisdn  1   msisdn  A   6627292     (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE        
    subscription_import     1   service     1   service     A   18  (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE        
    subscription_import     1   short_code  1   adn     A   18  (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE        
    subscription_import     1   operator    1   operator    A   18  (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE        
    subscription_import     1   channel     1   channel     A   18  (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE
```

index on subscription tables

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
subscription    0   PRIMARY     1   id  A   2179811     (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE        
subscription    1   msisdn  1   msisdn  A   2179811     (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE        
subscription    1   service     1   service     A   19  (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE        
subscription    1   short_code  1   adn     A   19  (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE        
subscription    1   operator    1   operator    A   19  (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE        
subscription    1   channel     1   channel_subscribe   A   19  (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE        
subscription    1   subscribed_from     1   subscribed_from     A   2179811     (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE        
subscription    1   subscribed_until    1   subscribed_until    A   2179811     (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE        
subscription    1   active  1   active  A   19  (NULL)  (NULL)  YES     BTREE        
subscription    1   time_created    1   time_created    A   2179811     (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE        
subscription    1   time_updated    1   time_updated    A   2179811     (NULL)  (NULL)      BTREE
```

Create table command for subscription_import

```
CREATE TABLE `subscription_import` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `msisdn` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `service` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `adn` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `operator` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `channel` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `blacklist_status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `msisdn` (`msisdn`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `service` (`service`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `short_code` (`adn`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `operator` (`operator`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `channel` (`channel`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `date_created` (`date_created`),
  KEY `STATUS` (`status`),
  KEY `price` (`price`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33274291 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

create table command for table subscription

```
CREATE TABLE `subscription` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transaction_id_subscribe` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `transaction_id_unsubscribe` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `msisdn` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `service` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `adn` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `operator` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `channel_subscribe` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `channel_unsubscribe` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `subscribed_from` datetime NOT NULL,
  `subscribed_until` datetime NOT NULL,
  `partner` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `time_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `msisdn` (`msisdn`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `service` (`service`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `short_code` (`adn`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `operator` (`operator`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `channel` (`channel_subscribe`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `subscribed_from` (`subscribed_from`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `subscribed_until` (`subscribed_until`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `active` (`active`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `time_created` (`time_created`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `time_updated` (`time_updated`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7868759 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Maybe try using JOINS instead of INs

Comment: can you include the output from EXPLAIN (your query)?

Comment: Agreeing with Strawberry... Along the same lines, what is the goal of the query (i.e. what is the business logic this query is addressing, i.e. what is the question in plain English that this query is asking)? Simplifying the query will likely go a long way in improving performance.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: i've been given the create table command on above.

Comment: @john, the simple logic i want to take some data from table with reference to another table with a specific date

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `IN ( SELECT ...)`; it is very inefficient.  Instead use `JOIN`.  For `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )`, use `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE id IS NULL`.

Do not "hide" a column inside a function (whenever possible): `AND  DATE(b.date_created) = '2012-05-16'` can be turned into `AND  b.date_created = '2012-05-16'` if `date_created` is a DATE.  If it is a DATETIME, then do:

```
AND  b.date_created >= '2012-05-16'
AND  b.date_created  < '2012-05-16' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

With that, `INDEX(date_created)` can be used.  Even better might be the composite `INDEX(price, status, date_created)`.

`subscription` will need `INDEX(msisdn, blacklist_status, active)` after turning it into a `LEFT JOIN`.

`DATE(NOW())` is the same as `CURDATE()`.  But `WHERE  DATE(date_created) = DATE(NOW())` could probably be `WHERE date_created >= CURDATE()`.

`subscription_import` will need `INDEX(msisdn, date_created)`.

Is `msisdn` unique?  That is, could it be used as the 'natural' `PRIMARY KEY` instead of `id`?

Make those changes, performance will be better.  Then come back for more advice/abuse.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your preference for `JOIN` over `IN (SELECT ...)`? According to http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/ they perform the same.

Comment: I added a comment to that blog.

Comment: `WHERE EXISTS` or `WHERE NOT EXISTS` _may_ be as good as, or better than, `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: msisdn on subscription table its unique but on subscription import is not, because that is the result, so there is duplicate msisdn on subscription_import table.

Comment: for your suggestion, i already create this index. INDEX(price, status, date_created)

Comment: @TomasoAlbinoni i dont get it for left join operations replacing not in state, can you gave some clearly understanding with my case ?, thanks

Comment: @AmirRachman - I see 3 separate indexes, but no _composite_ index on the three columns in your `CREATE TABLE`.  They are quite different.

Comment: @RickJames, which one is better composite index or separate index ?, shall i create both composite and separate index ?

Comment: `INDEX(a,b)` is better than `INDEX(a)`.  More explanation, in [this](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1) and [this](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to select from a table where a JOIN to each of two other tables fails (there is no matching record in either.)

First establish the subscription records you want:

```
SELECT ...
FROM subscription b
WHERE DATE(b.date_created) = '2012-05-16'
    AND b.status = 0
    AND b.price IS NULL
```

Then you want to exclude cases where there is a qualifying match in tbl_blacklist.  So first match the cases where there *is* a match, but make it an exclusion by saying the matchid id is null

```
SELECT ...
FROM subscription b

(add)
| LEFT JOIN tbl_blacklist bl ON b.msisdn = bl.msisdn
|     AND bl.blacklist_status = '1'
+-    AND bl.active = '1'

WHERE DATE(b.date_created) = '2012-05-16'
    AND b.status = 0
    AND b.price IS NULL

+-    AND bl.id IS NULL
```

Then do the same for the second join:

```
SELECT ...
FROM subscription b
LEFT JOIN tbl_blacklist bl ON b.msisdn = bl.msisdn
    AND bl.blacklist_status = '1'
    AND bl.active = '1'

(add)
| LEFT JOIN subscription_import si ON b.msisdn = si.msisdn
|+    AND DATE(si.date_created) = CURRENT_DATE()

WHERE DATE(b.date_created) = '2012-05-16'
    AND b.status = 0
    AND b.price IS NULL
    AND bl.id IS NULL

|+    AND si.id IS NULL
```

I think I'm at least close enough that you can straighten the sense out.

In my experience MySQL has always been most efficient at JOINs, including OUTER JOINs. Not so much with EXISTS, and especially NOT EXISTS.

Comment: SELECT s.msisdn
FROM `xmp_new`.`subscription` s
LEFT JOIN `msisdntools`.`tbl_blacklist` bl ON s.msisdn = bl.msisdn
LEFT JOIN `msisdntools`.subscription_import si ON s.msisdn = si.msisdn
WHERE s.operator = 'xxxx'
AND DATE(s.subscribed_from) BETWEEN '2011-01-16' AND '2015-05-17'
AND DATE(si.date_created) = '2012-05-16' 
AND si.STATUS = 1
AND si.price IS NULL
AND bl.id IS NULL 
AND si.id IS NULL

Comment: My fault - the tests on si and bl need to be in the JOIN expression i.e. 
LEFT JOIN subscription_import si ON s..msidsn = si.msidsn 
    AND DATE(si.date_created) = '2012-05-16' 
    AND si.status = 1 
    AND si.prics IS NULL
LEFT JOIN tbl_blacklist bl ON s.msidsdn = bl.msidsdn
WHERE other global constraints
    AND si.id IS NULL
    AND bl.id IS NULL

Comment: thanks for your reply can you update your answer to <pre> code on above so i can see clearly :), thanks

Comment: hi @dkretz, what is s alias for ?, anyway, can you look on my create table structure, on subscription table there is no status and price, it is on subscription_import, still a lil bit confuse from your explanation, sorry anyway :)

Comment: after several trying, finally i understand what you mean, thanks @dkretz